# "Done" function in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example, I read Grunt documentation on Creating Tasks. In "Tasks can be asynchronous" section, there is a use case of "done" function, I wonder why do we need that.

```
grunt.registerTask('asyncfoo', 'My "asyncfoo" task.', function() {
  // Force task into async mode and grab a handle to the "done" function.
  var done = this.async();
  // Run some sync stuff.
  grunt.log.writeln('Processing task...');
  // And some async stuff.
  setTimeout(function() {
    grunt.log.writeln('All done!');
    done();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It's a callback to say the task is done, if a task is async it needs the callback to know when it's done (and if is fails or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the only way for Grunt to know when your task is complete when doing async work.

This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) provides quite a bit of detail of what async in JS means and how to work with it.

Basically, `setTimeout` calls your callback function 1 second later. However, grunt has no idea when your callback is complete, as `setTimeout` itself returns immediately once it is called. Therefore, the `done()` function exists to provide you a way to tell grunt that your task is complete, whenever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt internally has a flag that determines if a task should be marked as complete when the task-function finishes or if it should be handled asynchronously. By default Grunt runs tasks synchronously and the `this.async()` call toggles this flag.

The "synchronous-by-default" design decision was probably made to make simple tasks easier to write where you could use fs.writeSync etc., which is definitely a valid approach albeit gets in the way with at least the kind of tasks that I usually write nowadays.

Grunt was also created before Promises became a viable solution for callback-hells, so there's that too.

I'm pretty sure there are also other reasons for this that I'm not aware of :)